# Cannot get custom user control to receive focus in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, forms, user-controls, keyup

I have a windows forms app (using .net / c#) which has a single form.  The form has no controls placed in it from the design view.

I also have custom "Screen" class which inherits from the user control class and is sized to fit exactly the form.  The screen class has a number of event handlers which can call back to the form that they are added to.

I have an array of Screen objects which are programatically created and added to the form as controls.

```
foreach(Screen s in screens)
{
    Controls.Add(s);
}
```

Clicking next or previous buttons on any of the screens indirectly calls an appropriate method (via event handler) in the form - the form then handles switching the screens in and out via the Visible and Enabled properties - ie when a screen needs to be removed or displayed the appropriate Visible and Enabled properties are set to false and true respectively.

Each Screen is responsible for the code that controls what it displays, the form code simply handles the flow from one screen to another.

So an example of the next button handler in the main form might be something like

```
screens[currScreen].Visible = false;
screens[currScreen].Enabled = false;
currScreen++;
screens[currScreen].Visible = true;
screens[currScreen].Enabled = true;
```

This all works great, until I try to handle the escape key.

I want to be able to let the user press the escape key to quit the app.  So my first thought was to simply add the following code to each screen when it is programatically initialised...

```
screen[n].KeyUp += OnKeyUP;  // Where on key up is an event handler in the main form
```

the idea here was that I can capture the event in the control and handle it in the form to call...

```
private void OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    { 
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

I know this type of event capturing works as I already use if for certain mouse operations, but it never works for the keyboard.  So I also tried putting the event handler just in my screen class and this didn't work either.

The I realised that perhaps the control doesn't have focus so isn't capturing the keyboard.  So I added the following debug code in the form...

```
        Console.WriteLine("Control: {0} - Focus = {1}", this.ToString(), this.Focused);
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Control: {0} - Focus = {1}", c.ToString(), c.Focused);
        }
```

And nothing has focus, so I'm not sure what does have focus?

Also I can't seem to get anything to take the focus, I've tried calling .Activate() on the controls and the form and also .Focus() and whenever I rerun the code above still nothing has focus.

If I remove the code which adds the Screen controls to the form and then run the code above the key strokes are detected by the form KeyUp event and the form has the focus.  Adding the controls seems to stop anything having focus.

Anyone any idea how I can get the Screen controls to receive the keyup events, or give them focus?  I'm sure it's something really obviously stupid that I'm doing wrong but I'm banging my head against a wall now.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a whole lot of question!